# R, How to keep rows after, and/or between values split by group?

Tags: r

Sorry my dput function was giving a nonsense output for some reason.  I have a df with User IDs and events.  I am trying to build a path for each user ID starting from the Event $identify.   How do I only keep the first 5 rows  after the $identify for each ID?  The output should have each ID plus the next 5 events.  The dataframe is already sorted by userID and Date so no need to do that just maintain the order.

Sample output

| ID | datetime | Event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ID1232 | 9:00AM | $identify |
| ID1232 | 9:01AM | Dropdown Menu |

Repeated for each ID

```
testset <- wrapr::build_frame(
   "user_id"                               , "datetime"        , "event"                                   |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Settings"                |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Dropdown Menu - View Profile"            |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Profile - Edit"                          |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Profile - Close"                         |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Directory"               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:11 AM", "Directory - Close"                       |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:12 AM", "2D - Directory Icon"                     |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:12 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "Directory - Close"                       |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Settings"                |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "Dropdown Menu - View Profile"            |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "Profile - Edit"                          |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "Profile' - Save"                         |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Help"                    |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "Help - Close"                            |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 10:27 AM", "Chat - Search User"                      |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 11:47 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 11:55 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Agenda"                  |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 11:55 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:43 AM" , "$identify"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:43 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:43 AM" , "Onboarding - Next"                       |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:44 AM" , "Dimension Choice - Choice Made"          |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:44 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:46 AM" , "Dimension Choice - Choice Made"          |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:46 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:46 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Settings"                |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:46 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Sound Off"               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:47 AM" , "Chat - Search User"                      |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:47 AM" , "Chat - Invite a Person to Groupchat"     |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:47 AM" , "Chat - Enter Message"                    |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:50 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:50 AM" , "Dimension Choice - Choice Made"          |
     "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "9/21/21 9:50 AM" , "Chat - Join a Videochat"                 |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:32 PM" , "$identify"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:32 PM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:32 PM" , "Onboarding - Next"                       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:32 PM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:32 PM" , "2D - Agenda Icon"                        |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:32 PM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:36 PM" , "Agenda - Close"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:36 PM" , "2D - Directory Icon"                     |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:36 PM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:36 PM" , "Profile - View"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:37 PM" , "Profile - Close"                         |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:37 PM" , "Directory - Next page participant"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:37 PM" , "Directory - Filter"                      |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/21/21 8:38 PM" , "Directory - Close"                       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:00 AM", "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:00 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "Personal Agenda - Join The Session"      |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "Presentation - Open Modal"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:02 AM", "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "Presentation - Close Modal"              |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "Presentation - Open Modal"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "Personal Agenda - Join The Session"      |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:31 AM", "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Presentation - Close Modal"              |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Personal Agenda - Remove from my Agenda" |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Dropdown Menu - Agenda"                  |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Agenda - Past Presentations"             |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 2:30 PM" , "Agenda - Close"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 7:48 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:00 AM" , "Login - Login Button"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:00 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:01 AM" , "2D - Agenda Icon"                        |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:01 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:39 AM" , "Agenda - Close"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:39 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:39 AM" , "2D - Agenda Icon"                        |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:49 AM" , "Presentation - Open Modal"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:49 AM" , "Agenda - Join the Session"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:49 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:49 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:50 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:50 AM" , "Presentation - Close Modal"              |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "2D - Agenda Icon"                        |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Agenda - Join the Session"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Presentation - Open Modal"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:51 AM" , "Presentation - Close Modal"              |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "$identify"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "3D - Agenda Icon"                        |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "Agenda - Join the Session"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "Presentation - Open Modal"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:52 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:53 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:56 AM" , "Presentation - Close Modal"              |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:56 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:56 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:57 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:57 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:57 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:57 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Agenda"                  |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:57 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:57 AM" , "Agenda - Add to my Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Agenda - Close"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Open"                    |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Dropdown Menu - Agenda"                  |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Agenda - Add to my Agenda"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Agenda - Close"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Rooms Nav - Open"                        |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "3D - Join a Session Icon"                |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Presentation - Open Modal"               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:58 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 8:59 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:00 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:00 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:02 AM" , "Personal Agenda - Join The Session"      |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:02 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:02 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:11 AM" , "Profile - View"                          |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:12 AM" , "Profile - Close"                         |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:12 AM" , "Presentation - Watch Presentation"       |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:16 AM" , "Page View"                               |
     "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "9/22/21 9:16 AM" , "Presentation - Close Modal"              )
```

How would I alter the code below to start with

```
test2<-testset%>%
  arrange(user_id, datetime)%>%
  group_by(user_id)%>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(event == "Welcome - Confirm Emails")) %>%
  group_by(user_id, group) %>%
  filter(event[1] == "Welcome - Confirm Emails") %>%
  summarise(touches = paste(event, collapse = "_"),
            first_touch = min(datetime))%>%
  slice(1:(which(event == "$identify")))%>%
  ungroup()
```

this did not work.  After running the code with the initial answer I realize I need to have identify as the last event, when followed by  "Welcome - Confirm Emails"

Comment: One of your `user_id`s has two `$identify` instances. If you intend to count them separately (they occurred twenty minutes apart), then you need to specify that in your question (and verify that the code you have accepted does what you need).

Comment: They both worked for my eda purpose I appreciate both of your input.  I am trying to track how many steps it takes for a new user to complete registration on the a website.  So  I am collapsing these into sequences.  I think I may need to use this same method but  try a different starting variable.  Is there a way to set a slice from one variable to another?

Comment: testset2<-testset%>%
  arrange(user_id, datetime)%>%
  group_by(user_id)%>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(event == "$identify")) %>%
  group_by(user_id, group) %>%
  filter(event[1] == "$identify" & row_number() <= 5) %>%
  summarise(touches = paste(event, collapse = "_"),
            first_touch = min(datetime))%>%

Comment: Comments are not good for showing significant amounts of code. Please, either [edit] your question and put it there, or (since this is morphing a bit) consider a new question. In so doing, I think you may want to reframe the approach so that rows between events "A" and "B" are in one group, and between events "B" and "C" are in another group, etc (all by `user_id`). That is, what are each of your "starting variables" (and likely terminating variables for each set) and we can determine sequences from there.

Comment: @r2evans I changed the question and added in the code I tried.

Comment: I *think* you are intending two different results here: the first is what you originally asked, which is every row with `$identify` and the four following rows; the second is "every row between `Welcome..` and `$identify`. The two outputs are completely different, is that right?

Comment: @r2evans yes that is correct.  Every row inclusive of those variables, still maintaining order and group....I realized that the Welcome Email group is the right starting variable because the number of rows summarized equals the amount of people on record

Comment: See my edit, d3hero23, I think it's a good start.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you. this worked.  I appreciate your help.  One last question is just what does the cumsum group by actually do?  I understand cumsum in terms of cumulative sum of numbers but not completely understanding why it works with a character value

Comment: When the conditional inside of `cumsum` changes from `FALSE` to `TRUE`, it means that we intend for a group to *start* at that row. The subsequent rows are likely `FALSE`, and `cumsum(c(T,F,F,F))` will keep those all in the same group. The next `TRUE` will increment and start a new group. It's a shortcut mechanism for creating groups; when done within another grouping mechanism (e.g., `ave`, `group_by`), it's a very powerful tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a straight-forward grouping operation, but there's a twist: at least one `user_id` has multiple `$identify` lines, in which case you need to check for both.

### base R

```r
testset$group <- ave(testset$event, testset$user_id,
                     FUN = function(z) cumsum(z == "$identify"))
keep <- ave(testset$event, testset[,c("user_id", "group")],
            FUN = function(z) {
              if (length(z) && z[1] == "$identify") (seq_along(z) <= 5) else FALSE
            }) == "TRUE"
testset[keep,]
#                                  user_id        datetime                          event group
# 25  0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 9:43 AM                      $identify     1
# 26  0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 9:43 AM                      Page View     1
# 27  0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 9:43 AM              Onboarding - Next     1
# 28  0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 9:44 AM Dimension Choice - Choice Made     1
# 29  0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 9:44 AM                      Page View     1
# 40  01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/21/21 8:32 PM                      $identify     1
# 41  01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/21/21 8:32 PM                      Page View     1
# 42  01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/21/21 8:32 PM              Onboarding - Next     1
# 43  01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/21/21 8:32 PM                      Page View     1
# 44  01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/21/21 8:32 PM               2D - Agenda Icon     1
# 108 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:52 AM                      $identify     2
# 109 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:52 AM                      Page View     2
# 110 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:52 AM               3D - Agenda Icon     2
# 111 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:52 AM                      Page View     2
# 112 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:52 AM      Agenda - Join the Session     2
```

### dplyr

Similar to the other answer, handling multiple instances of `$identify` differently.

```r
library(dplyr)
testset %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(event == "$identify")) %>%
  group_by(user_id, group) %>%
  filter(event[1] == "$identify" & row_number() <= 5) %>%
  ungroup()
```

### data.table

```r
library(data.table)
testsetDT <- as.data.table(testset)
testsetDT[, group := cumsum(event == "$identify"), by = user_id
          ][, .SD[event[1] == "$identify" & seq_len(.N) <= 5,], by = .(user_id, group)
            ]
```

---

For your second need (return rows between two `event`s), it's difficult to test fully given that your data does not include `"Welcome..."`, but I'll use `"Page View"` instead:

```r
testset %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(event == "Page View")) %>%
  group_by(user_id, group) %>%
  filter(event[1] == "Page View" &
           "$identify" %in% event &
           (event == "$identify" | !cumany(event == "$identify"))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 5 x 4
#   user_id                              datetime         event                      group
#   <chr>                                <chr>            <chr>                      <int>
# 1 0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 11:55 AM Page View                      5
# 2 0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc 9/21/21 9:43 AM  $identify                      5
# 3 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:51 AM  Page View                     25
# 4 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:51 AM  Presentation - Close Modal    25
# 5 01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76 9/22/21 8:52 AM  $identify                     25
```

Similar mechanisms can be used for base R and `data.table` solutions if required.

---

Data

```r
testset <- structure(list(user_id = c("0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "0106d45f-deda-4205-894a-006c8afa5abc", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76", "01370990-cc35-4be4-8927-39e83b7f1e76"), datetime = c("9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:10 AM", "9/21/21 10:11 AM", "9/21/21 10:12 AM", "9/21/21 10:12 AM", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "9/21/21 10:13 AM", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "9/21/21 10:14 AM", "9/21/21 10:27 AM", "9/21/21 11:47 AM", "9/21/21 11:55 AM", "9/21/21 11:55 AM", "9/21/21 9:43 AM", "9/21/21 9:43 AM", "9/21/21 9:43 AM", "9/21/21 9:44 AM", "9/21/21 9:44 AM", "9/21/21 9:46 AM", "9/21/21 9:46 AM", "9/21/21 9:46 AM", "9/21/21 9:46 AM", "9/21/21 9:47 AM", "9/21/21 9:47 AM", "9/21/21 9:47 AM", "9/21/21 9:50 AM", "9/21/21 9:50 AM", "9/21/21 9:50 AM", "9/21/21 8:32 PM", "9/21/21 8:32 PM", "9/21/21 8:32 PM", "9/21/21 8:32 PM", "9/21/21 8:32 PM", "9/21/21 8:32 PM", "9/21/21 8:36 PM", "9/21/21 8:36 PM", "9/21/21 8:36 PM", "9/21/21 8:36 PM", "9/21/21 8:37 PM", "9/21/21 8:37 PM", "9/21/21 8:37 PM", "9/21/21 8:38 PM", "9/22/21 10:00 AM", "9/22/21 10:00 AM", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "9/22/21 10:01 AM", "9/22/21 10:02 AM", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "9/22/21 10:27 AM", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "9/22/21 10:30 AM", "9/22/21 10:31 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 10:58 AM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 2:30 PM", "9/22/21 7:48 AM", "9/22/21 8:00 AM", "9/22/21 8:00 AM", "9/22/21 8:01 AM", "9/22/21 8:01 AM", "9/22/21 8:39 AM", "9/22/21 8:39 AM", "9/22/21 8:39 AM", "9/22/21 8:49 AM", "9/22/21 8:49 AM", "9/22/21 8:49 AM", "9/22/21 8:49 AM", "9/22/21 8:50 AM", "9/22/21 8:50 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:51 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:52 AM", "9/22/21 8:53 AM", "9/22/21 8:56 AM", "9/22/21 8:56 AM", "9/22/21 8:56 AM", "9/22/21 8:57 AM", "9/22/21 8:57 AM", "9/22/21 8:57 AM", "9/22/21 8:57 AM", "9/22/21 8:57 AM", "9/22/21 8:57 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:58 AM", "9/22/21 8:59 AM", "9/22/21 9:00 AM", "9/22/21 9:00 AM", "9/22/21 9:02 AM", "9/22/21 9:02 AM", "9/22/21 9:02 AM", "9/22/21 9:11 AM", "9/22/21 9:12 AM", "9/22/21 9:12 AM", "9/22/21 9:16 AM", "9/22/21 9:16 AM"), event = c("Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Settings", "Dropdown Menu - View Profile", "Profile - Edit", "Profile - Close", "Dropdown Menu - Directory", "Page View", "Directory - Close", "2D - Directory Icon", "Page View", "Directory - Close", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Settings", "Dropdown Menu - View Profile", "Profile - Edit", "Profile' - Save", "Dropdown Menu - Help", "Page View", "Help - Close", "Chat - Search User", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Agenda", "Page View", "$identify", "Page View", "Onboarding - Next", "Dimension Choice - Choice Made", "Page View", "Dimension Choice - Choice Made", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Settings", "Dropdown Menu - Sound Off", "Chat - Search User", "Chat - Invite a Person to Groupchat", "Chat - Enter Message", "Page View", "Dimension Choice - Choice Made", "Chat - Join a Videochat", "$identify", "Page View", "Onboarding - Next", "Page View", "2D - Agenda Icon", "Page View", "Agenda - Close", "2D - Directory Icon", "Page View", "Profile - View", "Profile - Close", "Directory - Next page participant", "Directory - Filter", "Directory - Close", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Page View", "Personal Agenda - Join The Session", "Page View", "Presentation - Open Modal", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Presentation - Close Modal", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda", "Page View", "Presentation - Open Modal", "Page View", "Personal Agenda - Join The Session", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Presentation - Close Modal", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda", "Page View", "Personal Agenda - Remove from my Agenda", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Agenda", "Page View", "Agenda - Past Presentations", "Agenda - Close", "Page View", "Login - Login Button", "Page View", "2D - Agenda Icon", "Page View", "Agenda - Close", "Page View", "2D - Agenda Icon", "Presentation - Open Modal", "Agenda - Join the Session", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Page View", "Presentation - Close Modal", "2D - Agenda Icon", "Page View", "Agenda - Join the Session", "Presentation - Open Modal", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Page View", "Presentation - Close Modal", "$identify", "Page View", "3D - Agenda Icon", "Page View", "Agenda - Join the Session", "Page View", "Presentation - Open Modal", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Presentation - Close Modal", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Agenda", "Page View", "Agenda - Add to my Agenda", "Agenda - Close", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - My Agenda", "Page View", "Dropdown Menu - Open", "Dropdown Menu - Agenda", "Page View", "Agenda - Add to my Agenda", "Agenda - Close", "Rooms Nav - Open", "3D - Join a Session Icon", "Presentation - Open Modal", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Personal Agenda - Join The Session", "Page View", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Profile - View", "Profile - Close", "Presentation - Watch Presentation", "Page View", "Presentation - Close Modal")), row.names = c(NA, -150L), class = "data.frame")
```